# Error loading images from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, models

I have a question about showing images loaded from a mysql database in an Index view.

In my database table "deliverables" I have "item_id", "deliverable_image" and "afstudeerrichting_id". "item_id" and "afstudeerrichting_id" are FK from other tables.

I want to show the images when afstudeerrichting_id = ..

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = repository.GetIdsOfImages(1);
    return View(model.ToList());
}

public ActionResult ShowImage(int id)
{
    IQueryable<byte[]> data = repository.GetImages(id);
    byte[] firstimage = data.First();

    return File(firstimage, "image/png");
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public IQueryable<long> GetIdsOfImages(int afstudeerrichtingid)
{
    return from deliverable in entities.deliverables
           where deliverable.afstudeerichting_id.Equals(afstudeerrichtingid)
           select deliverable.item_id;
}
public IQueryable<byte[]> GetImages(int itemID)
{
    return from deliverable in entities.deliverables
           where deliverable.item_id.Equals(itemID)
           select deliverable.deliverable_image;
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach(var imgID in Model.DeliverablesIDsList)
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("ShowImage", "Deliverable", new { DeliverableID = imgID })" />
}
```

In my **Viewmodel** I have:

```
public List<long> DeliverablesIDsList { get; set; }
public int DeliverableID { get; set; }
```

But now I always get this error:

> he model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'GDMfrontEnd.Models.DeliverableViewModel'.

Does someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're sending to the view a list of int64 `repository.GetIdsOfImages(1).ToList()`  and the view requires a DeliverableViewModel, so you must create a model and put the list into the model and send it to the view

the action should looks like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = repository.GetIdsOfImages(1);
    DeliverableViewModel model = new DeliverableViewModel()
    model.DeliverablesIDsList = repository.GetIdsOfImages(1).ToList();
    return View(model); //send to the view a model type of DeliverableViewModel
}
```

now with ActionResult ShowImage, the action expect id parmeter and you're sending DeliverableID, so change de var name

```
public ActionResult ShowImage(int DeliverableID)
{
    IQueryable<byte[]> data = repository.GetImages(DeliverableID);
    byte[] firstimage = data.First();

    return File(firstimage, "image/png");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is now in my showImage action :/ He doesn't show the images :( Do you maybe know what the problem is? It looks like he doesn't come in the action...